# Redirect user to other website on when clicked on Add To Cart button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I need help in finding the correct hook for WooCommerce. I'm trying to integrate design-builder API with the WooCommerce store. I have to make a redirect to the builder's website when a customer clicks "Add To Cart" on the product page.
Example URL I need redirect to: [https://exampleurl.com/designBuilder/{UniqueID}](https://exampleurl.com/designBuilder/%7BUniqueID%7D)
{UniqueID} is generated with this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'woo_api_add_cart_item_data', 10, 4 );
function woo_api_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id, $quantity ) {

    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $unique_id = uniqid();

    //...Some code...


    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Is there a WooCommerce hook to change the "add to cart" redirection URL and pass some values from the product?

Comment: `woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect` check this

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Somehow it redirects me to wp-admin no matter what I type in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 10, 2);

function custom_woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect($url, $product) {

    $url = "https://exampleurl.com/designBuilder/{$product->get_id()} ";
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: It works but I need to get $cart_item_data['someMetaData']; of the product that was added to cart.

Comment: I've managed to do it. Thanks for your help!!